# Javascript not changing style of new added element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, settimeout

So I want to have a very simple system where it frequently updates a list with a maximum of 10 items. The code is not done, but I'm getting a problem.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <script>

        function addText(txt) {
            li_array = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

            new_line = document.createElement("li");
            node = document.createTextNode(txt);
            new_line.appendChild(node);

            latest_message = li_array[li_array.length - 1];

            latest_message.parentNode.insertBefore(new_line, latest_message.nextSibling);

            // DELETE 11TH MESSAGE
            if (li_array.length == 10) {
                setTimeout(removeOldestText(), 1000);
            }
        }

        function removeOldestText() {
            document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].parentNode.removeChild(li_array[0]);
        }

        function sendText(txt) {
            addText(txt);
            document.getElementsByTagName('li')[document.getElementsByTagName('li').length - 1].style.fontSize = "3vh";
        }

    </script>

    <body>
        <div id="feed_div">
            <ul id="feed_ul">
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

li {
    font-size: 0vh;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, font-size 1s; /* Safari */
    transition: opacity 1s, font-size 1s;
}
```

When I call the addText() function, it adds the new li. But there are two problems.

- The timeout for the removal of the oldest element doesn't work. If there is an 11th element, it will remove it instantly instead of waiting one second.
- The new added text should come in with a nice animation. But after it is added, the new font-size isn't updated, which is supposed to be done in the last line of the sendText function. However, when I copy and paste the last line in the console, it works perfectly. Why is Javascript not excecuting this line?

Thank you so much for you help guys!

Comment: @blex I just tried it. But the element doesn't get removed at all after I removed them. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You are calling `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` several times, which is very inefficient. It's a live collection, so you only need to get it once and it will be automatically updated as *li* elements are added and removed from the document. Also, it's assigned to an implicit global variable, *li_array*. So do it once globally, then you can do: `li_array[0].parentNode.removeChild(li_array[0])`.

Comment: @blex I got the delayed removal working now. Thanks!

Comment: @RobG I was worried that it wouldn't get updated so that's why I called it again every time I needed it. I'll define it in the beginning now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, `latest_message = li_array[li_array.length - 1]; latest_message.parentNode.insertBefore(new_line, latest_message.nextSibling)` simply adds the new *li* as the last one, so replace with `li_array.appendChild(new_line)`.

Comment: @RobG Oh ofcourse, that's pretty stupid. Awesome feedback, thank you so much ^^

Comment: I gave it a try: http://jsfiddle.net/x17Lufhy/

Comment: @blex Do you know why it does work with classes but not with direct styling? Also, what are those 50 ms delays for?

Comment: CSS transitions are only applied on a CSS state change (e.g. `:hover`, or a change of class). In your example, JS just sets the font-size directly (there is no CSS state change, so no animation). As for the 50ms timeouts, I'm not sure why, but without them, the animations don't work properly. I don't know what's causing this, that's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that should be `li_array[0].parentNode.appendChild(new_line)`.